# Java and C++ - String

Tags: java, c++

I have a Java Client and C++ server. All values are sent as byte array. The numeric values are received fine but the string values when stored in char array in C++, have special characters like new page or new line feed at the end of the value. Can someone suggest a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - use [google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) for serialization/deserialization. It's an open-source, stable, easy-to-use cross-platform package.

Answer (score 1):

How are you serialising / deserialising?  You should decide on an encoding (for example ASCII) then write the length of the string first as an int, that way the server can read the int and will know how many bytes to read of the string.

Once its read the bytes it just needs to tail the char* with a '\0' to terminate the string in the array.

Depending on what you are using to write the string in Java you would do something like:

```
writeInt(string.length());
writeBytes(string.getBytes("ASCII"));
```

and in your C++ server you would do the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure the server code is complying with your protocol at the byte level.

2) Make sure the client code is complying with your protocol at the byte level.

3) If you have done 1 and 2, and you still have problems, your protocol is broken. Most likely, it fails to properly specify how the server specifies where the strings end and how the client establishes where the strings end.